# Exporting dependencies from package which is existing vendor

Tags: go, glide-golang

I am new to golang and glide dependency management tool. I am trying to run `glide install` in created my company project. I have met an error about go-xorm library.

```
[ERROR] Update failed for github.com/go-xorm/xorm: Unable to get repository: Cloning into '/Users/xxx/.glide/cache/src/https-github.com-go-xorm-xorm'...
remote: Repository `go-xorm/xorm' is disabled.
remote: Please ask the owner to check their account.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/go-xorm/xorm/': The requested URL returned error: 403
: exit status 128
[ERROR] Failed to checkout packages: Unable to get repository: Cloning into '/Users/xxx/.glide/cache/src/https-github.com-go-xorm-xorm'...
remote: Repository `go-xorm/xorm' is disabled.
remote: Please ask the owner to check their account.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/go-xorm/xorm/': The requested URL returned error: 403
: exit status 128
```

It's seem that I am not able to download it from github because the owner made it disabled to clone.

How can I fix this error or Is there any way to export directly from local vendor without fetching from github. I am sure that the package is already on my local vendor folder. Thank you so much!!!

Comment: Have you taken note of the comment in [the glide readme](https://github.com/Masterminds/glide) "The Go community is now using Go Modules to handle dependencies. Please consider using that instead of Glide. Glide is now mostly unmaintained"? If you are new to Go I highly recommend using [modules](https://go.dev/blog/using-go-modules).

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Glide is deprecated since several years. Move on an use Modules.

Comment: This project is working well on productions. I just wanna to install on my local environment for fixing tiny bugs. As you guys suggested, I'll move on to Modules later. Thank for your comment.

Comment: @blami This is my first question on stackoverfolw. I've never known about that. I'll be more cautious in my next question. Thanks for your warning!

Answer (score 1):

This is because XORM moved from [Github](https://github.com/go-xorm/xorm) (repo is still available as Public Archive) to [Gitea](https://gitea.com/xorm/xorm) and instead of `github.com/go-xorm/xorm` they now use `xorm.io/xorm`.

I'd recommend to stop using `glide` completely and replace it with Go Modules based workflow; but if you must use it, you will need to remove `github.com/go-xorm/xorm` from your `glide.yaml`, add `xorm.io/xorm` (you can use `glide get` to do so) and fix your imports everywhere in codebase.

Comment: Thank for your answer! I've actually added and installed `xorm.io/xorm` before. But, It asked me a lot of  function name changes. I just want to install this project on the local environment to fix tiny bug in production. So I pleased to find any ways to fix this error As soon as possible.

Comment: @TrươngQuangThắng I don't think there's a good way to make `glide install` work with old repo. You can try cloning that repo manually into your `vendor/` directory in your local env (that's what I guess glide does anyway) but it might not work.